# Subgroup of Index 2 is Normal - If $g \not \in H$, then $gH= G/H$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the following proof:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Index_2_is_Normal

Specifically the part:

> If $g\not\in H$, then $gH=G/H$ as there are only two cosets and the cosets partition G.

Since $G/H = \{Ha : a \in G\}$, then doesn't this simply mean (and since $H$ is seen normal) that $gH=$ "all cosets". Isn't it trivial to state that $gH$ must equal "all cosets"? Why then does one need the notion "as there are only two cosets and the cosets partition $G$."?

Comment: No. This means left cosets are the same as right cosets, and it is a consequence of the index being 2.

Answer (score 6):

They wrote $G\setminus H$, not $G/H$. The latter is the quotient group, the former is the complement of $H$ in $G$, i.e. $G\setminus H = \{g \in G \mid g \not\in H\}$. As the cosets of $H$ partition $G$ and $H$ has index two, there are two cosets, one of which is $H$ and the other is necessarily $G\setminus H$.

Comment: It's also an example of why I don't like the notation $G \setminus H$ for set difference.